# Dot in Column name not supported while creating TDE Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

We are importing csv data into marklogic. Some of the columns have a dot(.) in their names. It is getting loaded fine into MarkLogic (along with the dot).

However, when we are creating TDE template to create a view, the dot is not being accepted. Throws me the error below:

```
[1.0-ml] TDE-INVALIDTEMPLATE: (err:FOER0000) Invalid TDE template: TDE-INVALIDSQLNAMENODE: Invalid SQL object name: "DataType." for /tde:template/tde:rows/tde:row/tde:columns/tde:column[3]/tde:name
```

I can replace the dot with an underscore, but was looking for any alternate suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tde.xsd a name is defined like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="name">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            A generic name type.
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:NCName">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:pattern value="[^.\-\p{Z}]+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Meaning, a dot in a column name is not allowed.
You can find the xsd in your MarkLogic installation directory in `Config/tde.xsd`.

I would suggest replacing the dot with a underscore or use camelCase for your column names.

Comment: Thank you. That helps. I wonder why is it restricted that way when it is well allowed as an xml element. Should I be raising it as a bug?

Comment: I'd say they should support dots, because you can have them in sql too. So yes, raise a bug/feature request.